# MySQL синтаксис (объединить 5 таблиц в запросе)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM lessons, lesson_1, lesson_2 
WHERE lessons.id = lesson_1.id & lessons.id = lesson_2.id
```

Мне нужно вывести из 5 таблиц все данные, у которых равны id. Так не правильно и не работает. Подскажите как сделать пожалуйста!

Comment: вместо `&` надо писать `AND` а на остальное ответить невозможно. просто объединение 5 таблиц имело бы смысл если бы во всех 5 таблицах отношения были один к одному. но такую БД сложно представить, обычно отношения все таки один ко многим и запрос пишется под конкретную задачу когда перед глазами есть вся структура БД и данные

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM lessons JOIN 
     lesson_1 USING (id) JOIN 
     lesson_2 USING (id)
```

И так далее для других таблиц.

[Документация.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: Спасибо! подскажи с запросом
SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE state = '1' AND current = '1'" В чем ошибка?

Comment: В лишней кавычке в конце? Лучше задайте отдельный вопрос!

Answer (score -1):

Используйте алиасы

```
SELECT table1.id AS t1, table2.id AS t2 ...
```

И т.д.